# ESP8266 - How does it understand what "AT+RST" means without the firmware

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266

I am new to ESP8266 and to the electronics world. I request you to please be patient if I am mis-understanding a point.

I am using ESP8266-01.
I successfully re-flashed the at official ai-thinker firmware version 1.1.1 to my module and I noticed that it was being written at memory location 0x00000.
Later I successfully uploaded a basic blink program using Arduino ide. Again the program was written to the memory location 0x00000(over-writing the firmware I guess).

I want to use it as a web server. The code for that uses the AT commands, something like "Serial.println("AT+RST");"

Now from what I understand the firmware would be over-written. Then how would the module understand what "AT+RST" means?

Thanks

Comment: How "web server" and AT commands are related is unknown to me...modem connection may let you connect to your Arduino web server but that's all. Anyway AT commands (reset, in your example...) is _understood_ (forgive me if I simplify) directly by ESP8266 chip (don't forget to do proper connections unless you want to handle input data to later forward to ESP chip) and your sketch may be completely empty (chip will handle all known commands for you).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
"How 'web server' and AT commands are related is unknown to me" : What i meant was, to setup the server I would be issuing AT commands to the wifi module.
"Anyway AT commands are understood directly by ESP8266 chip" : If that is the case, why does the module stop responding to the "AT" command(s) from serial monitor after I have uploaded a blank/blink sketch?

Comment: Did you connect serial input pins to ESP pins? If not then with a blank sketch it won't receive any data.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : I have an ardunio uno which I use to Transmit/Receive messages via the serial monitor provided in the Ardunio IDE. If I flash the official firmware, the AT responds with an 'OK'. After uploading the sketch, nothing. And since my sketch is written to the memory location 0x00000, I assume the firmware has been over-written and along with it the ability to understand the 'AT' command.

Comment: I explain what I mean: with an empty sketch ESP won't receive data from input pins unless you **physically** connect them.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti : I think the pins are connected the right way. It is as following: RX(esp)-----RX(uno) ; TX(esp)----TX(uno) ; GND(esp)---GND(separate power source); CH_PD(esp)---3.3V(uno) ; VCC(esp) - VCC(separate power source) ; GPIO-0(esp) (leave open or pull up for normal, pull down to upload new firmware). Something close to http://imgur.com/AidHic4

Answer (score 2):

"Arduino" is more than just the IDE you see and the boards (e.g. Uno). Arduino is also a kind of firmware/OS that runs on those boards. A sketch you write in the IDE is compiled together with the firmware into a single package that's written to memory.

There are a few more hints at https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino:

> This project brings support for ESP8266 chip to the Arduino
>   environment. It lets you write sketches using familiar Arduino
>   functions and libraries, and run them directly on ESP8266, no external
>   microcontroller required.
>
> ESP8266 Arduino core comes with libraries to communicate over WiFi
>   using TCP and UDP, set up HTTP, mDNS, SSDP, and DNS servers, do OTA
>   updates, use a file system in flash memory, work with SD cards,
>   servos, SPI and I2C peripherals.

When you hit that 'Upload' button in the IDE you're effectively *replacing* anything that's been written to the ESP8266 before.

Comment: "A sketch you write in the IDE is compiled together with the firmware into a single package that's written to memory", this makes sense and if this is the case then the 'AT' command should work after the empty sketch has been uploaded. I must be doing something wrong since I am not getting any response after uploading the empty sketch. I will spend some more time playing with it to get the desired result and post back. Thanks.

Comment: That'd be different question then. Two final links I'd like to share: http://j.mp/1OqRbG4, http://j.mp/1OqR2Tb. And if this was helpful and to the point: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/257994. Over and out.

Answer (score 0):

This question is wrong on many levels.

1. It was based on the assumption that "Serial.println("AT+RST")" was a command to the esp while in reality the programmer meant it as a logging message to the serial monitor.
2. I had asked "How does it understand what “AT+RST” means without the firmware". The answer is that it doesn't and it can't unless I write some code in my sketch to handle it. The firmware is a kind of interpretter. It accepts a command in a particular format (e.g. "AT \n"), parses it, executes some corresponding low level function and returns the result. 
   After I have uploaded a sketch and over-written the AT firmware, the interpretter code is gone and hence the esp cannot interpret/understand the AT command.

@AdrianoRepetti:

1. "How "web server" and AT commands are related is unknown to me" - You are right, they are not related. My bad.
2. "Anyway AT commands is understood directly by ESP8266 chip" I doubt it.

Thanks for your answers.

This question is not adding any knowledge to anything. I think it should be deleted.